# use parameter in CREATE DATABASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to specify the path where data file and log file is created in a SQL script using parameters. Here is what I wrote:

```
DECLARE @DataFilePath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DataFilePath = N'C:\ProgramData\Gemcom\'

DECLARE @LogFilePath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DataFilePath = N'C:\ProgramData\Gemcom\'


USE master
Go
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
ON 
PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDB_Data', FILENAME = @DataFilePath )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestDB_Log', FILENAME = @LogFilePath  )

GO
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When I try to run it in SQL Server Management Studio, I got the error

> Incorrect syntax near
>   '@DataFilePath'.

I am wondering if what I intended to do is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give a value to `@LogFilePath`, instead you set @DataFilePath twice

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to use dynamic SQL

```
SELECT @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE TestDB ON PRIMARY ( NAME = ''TestDB_Data'', 
 FILENAME = ' + quotename(@DataFilePath) + ') LOG ON ( NAME = ''TestDB_Log'', 
FILENAME = ' + quotename(@LogFilePath) + ')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using SQLCMD mode. In SSMS, under the Query menu, choose SQLCMD Mode, then run this script.

```
:SETVAR DataFilePath N'C:\ProgramData\Gemcom\TestDB.mdf'    
:SETVAR LogFilePath N'C:\ProgramData\Gemcom\TestDB.ldf'

USE master
Go
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
ON 
PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDB_Data', FILENAME = $(DataFilePath) )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestDB_Log', FILENAME = $(LogFilePath)  )

GO
```