# Creating a database programmatically in SQL Server with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

As of right now I have a working piece of code, that looks something like this:

```
string sqlCreateDBQuery = " CREATE DATABASE "
                                  + "["+databaseName+"]"
                                  + " ON PRIMARY "
                                  + " (NAME = Data, "
                                  + " FILENAME = '" + strDataPath + databaseName + ".mdf', "
                                  + " FILEGROWTH = 1MB) "
                                  + " LOG ON (NAME = Log, "
                                  + " FILENAME = '" + strLogPath + databaseName + "_log.ldf', "
                                  + " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "
                                  + " COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ;";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, connection);
```

This has, with my current understanding, the potential issue of SQL-Injection attacks and well, user input errors.

So my question is, how do I **safely** create a database programmatically on an SQL Server where the user is able to name the database?

I know that one should use parameterized SQL-Queries to avoid SQL-Injection attempts, but for some reason I can´t seem to figure out how to do this for creating a new database or users/logins.

I´ve also read, that there is the option to use the SQL Server Management Object API as described in this answer here: [Creating a database programmatically in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9015178/2641504)

Unfortunately this is not an option for us.

As of right now I haven´t figured out how to use a parameterized Query for this task.
This is what I would assume what the Code should look like to achieve this, but with no working result.

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = " CREATE DATABASE "
                              + "@dbName"
                              + " ON PRIMARY "
                              + " (NAME = Data, "
                              + " FILENAME = @dataPath, " 
                              + " FILEGROWTH = 1MB) "
                              + " LOG ON (NAME = Log, "
                              + " FILENAME = @logPath, " 
                              + " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "
                              + " COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ;";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbName", StrDBName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataPath", $"{strDataPath}{StrDBName}.mdf");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logPath", $"{strLogPath}{StrDBName}_log.ldf");
```

I´ve also read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626850/sql-server-use-parameter-in-create-database) that this should be possible with dynamic SQL, but sadly all my attempts either ended in Syntax errors or the parameters not being replaced by the actual values.

Am I missing something here or is this just not as trivial as I initially thought?

Comment: You can't do that, you must use dynamic sql in this case. Parameters can only be used as value placeholders in SUDI statements, you can't use them in ALTER/DROP/CREATE statements.

Comment: How exactly would this look like? My attempt looked like this: https://pastebin.com/qmVJLJ9a

Comment: Your first code fragment is dynamic sql, that is the only way to do this. You will have to manually sanitize the input strings.

Comment: You could add a step to validate any strings you are using, to flag up any non-alphanumeric characters.  This might need extending slightly; you might decide that a database name can allow underscores (for example), but definitely prevent any semi-colons.  It's not ideal, but it's better than nothing.