# Wix: Is there any wix command to create database user?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6, wix-extension

Is they any wix command I can use to create database and to also add a user to the database?
If yes, is there any example on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you try the following:

1. Create your sql database using techniques mentioned here: [Wix: create a sql server database at a specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624727/wix-create-a-sql-server-database-at-a-specified-location)
2. Create a user via SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx
3. Run your sql via wix using: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/09/running-update-sql-scripts-during-minor-upgrades-with-wix/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the SQL extension [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/sql_xsd_index.htm).

You'll need to add a reference to it in your installer project, an example of this can be found [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database).